# Removing one items from an array and moving the others backwards

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'll just go straight to the point. I want to move the items in an array in a uniform difference, let's say I have this.

```
string[] fruits = { "Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Pear", "Mango" };
```

For example, let's say I want to remove the "Apple" so I'll do this.

```
fruits[1] = "";
```

Now all that left are:

```
{ "Banana", "", "Watermelon", "Pear", "Mango" }
```

How do I *really* remove the Apple part and get only:

```
{ "Banana", "Watermelon", "Pear", "Mango" }
```

Note that the index of all the items from "Watermelon" until the end of the array moves 1 backward. Any ideas?

Comment: @Morten: Please never suggest using non-generic containers like ArrayList. Use generic `List<T>` instead!

Comment: The problem is, this is a teamwork project. My friends started the project and used arrays. I can't just restart the project to change the application to be using lists.

Comment: @MortenAnderson there's really no need to every use ArrayList (unless you're using .NET 1).

Comment: @Naufal: Actually you can use `T[] arr = list.ToArray();`. Also when you need a flexible container, use `List<T>`. If you need fixed-size, use `T[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use Arrays, you can use Linq to filter your list and convert to array:

```
  string[] fruits = { "Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Pear", "Mango" };

  fruits = fruits.Where(f => f != "Apple").ToArray();
```

If you're not required to use an array, look at the [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). A list allows items to be added and removed.

Comment: this will remove all the "Apple"'s

Comment: I'll try this, since I will only contain one per item.

Answer (score 10):

The `List` class is the right one for you. It provides a method `Remove` which automatically moves the following elements backwards.

Comment: Ok, my team has allowed me to change the array into lists, I'll use this.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Wouter's answer, if you want to remove by item index rather than item value, you could do:

```
fruits = fruits.Where((s, i) => i != 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for( int i = 1;  i + 1 < fruits.Length;  i++ )
    fruits[i] = fruits[i + 1];
fruits = System.Array.Resize( fruits, fruits.Length - 1 );
```

If you do not care about the order of the fruit in the array, a smarter way to do it is as follows:

```
fruits[1] = fruits[fruits.Length - 1];
fruits = System.Array.Resize( fruits, fruits.Length - 1 );
```

Comment: I know that.... actually my program is a favorite fruit picker. I know that fruit is uncountable so it has another array.
fruits actually stands for Fruit Special in my app.

Comment: C-:= You know, when I used to learn English, 30 years ago, I learned that it is uncountable. But I looked it up just now to make sure I am not saying incorrect things, and dictionary.com says that plural is fruits. So I do not know whether this is an American idiom, (back then I learned British English) or whether the language has changed since then. So, I removed that part from my answer.

Comment: @Naufal: You definitely need to use `List<T>`!

Comment: @Mike: Interesting note. I decided to [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=fruits+plural+form) and found [this WikiDictionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruit#Usage_notes)

Comment: MikeNakis, my teacher told me so that plural for fruit is fruit. She's American, I'm confused right now, also if you type "fruits" in MSWs Woord no spelling error will be shown (the red underline).
abatishchev nice find

Comment: This has already been discussed on stackexchange: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25147/is-using-fruits-as-the-plural-of-fruit-acceptable

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the most useful things a new programmer can do is study and understand the various collection types.

While I think the List option that others have mentioned is probably what you are looking for, it's worth looking at a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class if you are doing a lot of insertions and deletions and not a lot of looking up by index.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I used lists and arrays to remove an item from an array. Note I also show you how to use linq to search an array full of bad names to remove. Hope this helps someone.

```
public static void CheckBadNames(ref string[] parts)
    {
        string[] BadName = new string[] {"LIFE", "ESTATE" ,"(",")","-","*","AN","LIFETIME","INTREST","MARRIED",
                                         "UNMARRIED","MARRIED/UNMARRIED","SINGLE","W/","/W","THE","ET",
                                         "ALS","AS", "TENANT" };

        List<string> list = new List<string>(BadName); //convert array to list

        foreach(string part in list)
        {
            if (BadName.Any(s => part.ToUpper().Contains(s)))
            {
                list.Remove(part);
            }
        }

        parts = list.ToArray(); // convert list back to array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner 3 years ago, I started making the software that I'm still working on today. I used an array for 'PartyMembers' of the game, and I'm basically today regretting it and having to spend a ton of time converting all this hard coded $#!t into a list.

Case in point, just use Lists if you can, arrays a nightmare in comparison.